# Como juntar as linhas de dois Dataframes com Python?

Tags: python, data, pandas

Olá! Preciso juntar linhas de dois dataframes com python - pandas.
Por exemplo, digamos que eu tenha esses dois dataframes

```
X |  Y  |  Z
1 |  2  |  3
4 |  5  |  6
```

e

```
A |  B  |  C
7 |  8  |  9
0 |  0  |  0
```

agora preciso juntar os dois dataframes, transformando no seguinte dataframe:

```
X  |  Y  |  Z
1  |  2  |  3
4  |  5  |  6
7  |  8  |  9 
0  |  0  |  0
```

Ou seja, preciso excluir o cabeçalho do dataframe 02 e adicionar as demais linhas no dataframe 01. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Eu mesmo consegui resolver. O comando é o seguinte:

Answer (score 3):

Existe a função [`.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) do pandas que concatena dois dataframes, mas para usá-la, as colunas devem ter o mesmo nome. Então podemos renomeá-las com o [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), outra função do pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
relacao_colunas = {'A':'X', 'B':'Y', 'C':'Z'}
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns=relacao_colunas)])
```